# how to show the inner contents in screenshot

Tags: javascript

i am using this script to download the screenshot of website page on click of a button, but the matter is that its fetching the whole images

```
// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
//@require       https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js
//@require       https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.min.js
// @grant        none
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $("body").prepend ( `
<button id="screenshot"> Get Screenshot</button>
<a id="test"></a>
<div></div>`);

 document.getElementById("screenshot").onclick = function() { genScreenshot();};
function genScreenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
      //$('#box1').html("");
            //$('#box1').append(canvas);

      if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 ||
                    navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
            {
        var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,'Test file.png');
      }
      else {
        $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
        $('#test').attr('download','Test file.png');
        $('#test')[0].click();
      }
  }
        });
    }
    // Your code here...
})();
```

Comment: How did you think writing all in CAPS is a good idea?

Comment: Nothing like that its such that caps was on so i write it like that otherwise i would be writing in camel case only, the result i want actually is that i want to get whole contents in screenshot that i am downloading using HTML2Canvas. but the thing is it is not displaying the whole content. Moreover it is skipping few images which is not acceptable.So kindly help if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) library to screenshot the page.

Additionally you can reference [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@e_mad_ehsan/getting-started-with-puppeteer-and-chrome-headless-for-web-scrapping-6bf5979dee3e) on how to configure the puppeteer module to screenshot the app.

In short basically go

```
npm i --save puppeteer
```

and then

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://github.com');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshots/github.png' });

  browser.close();
}

run();
```

**But** check out the tutorial